# Excel pivot showing row named "unknown"

Tags: pivot, ssas

I am trying to create a pivot using ssas cube. but I am seeing a row with label named "unknown".

I have checked the data in sql database and haven't seen any blank rows in the table.

Refer to below image.

[image]

I would like to remove unknown row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the unknown record is not on the Excel side, but in your data warehouse. The data warehouse with which the cube is built on should be set up with a key that will account for any "blank rows" in your Fact/Dimension joins. I would check those tables first for an "unknown" record, then trouble shoot the load of your Fact Table. Perfect book to read. [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247)

For instance,

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DimProduct
WHERE ProductKey = 1

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DimCustomer
WHERE CustomerKey = 1
```

will result in ...

[image]